# Any adjective to describe that something I already have?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

Is there any existing adjective to describe something I already have?

Like, I want to eat the food I already have. I don't want to buy anymore.

Is there any adjective alternative for "I already have"?

Comment: Just eat your existing food and when that is gone, you can buy more.

Comment: Sometimes, plain ***may*** (possibly with exaggerated stress) is all you need. Other times it might be better to add an extra word to make the meaning crystal clear: *I want to eat **my existing** food* (rather than buying some more food, or eating ***yours***).

Comment: Is existing a common usage to describe sundry and daily life object?

Answer (score 1):

If you say "I want to eat my food.", that would mean food that you have, not food that you don't have yet. The same would apply to most other contexts. If it's "mine", it's in my possession.

Comment: I would add only to Jack's answer that when disputes over ownership are concerned, it's worth bearing in mind the adage that: **Possession is nine tenths of the law**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_is_nine-tenths_of_the_law